# Car left in storage unit

Tags: contract-law, pennsylvania, motor-vehicle

Assume that Bob owns a car that is not up to code. Because he can't fix it, he stores it in a Pennsylvanian storage location without insurance.

Because Bob didn't pay that, it defaulted and the storage company sold the car to Charley.

Charley got the car running enough to get it into traffic and committed a parking violation. The police send the ticket for this to Bob. Is Bob liable for the tickets?

Comment: Your description is unclear and incomplete. Who was the owner at the time of the violations that prompted the parking tickets? In case you were the owner, why did the police issued the tickets given that your car was in a storage unit? What does the contract between you and the storage company say regarding default and/or applicable sanctions?

Comment: I decided to leave this question open because I understand what the question is trying to get at. I also understand why it has so many close votes. Maybe trying to rewrite the question in a less personal way while providing more details about the situation might help users better understand what's being asked.

Comment: @User37849012643 rewrite, depersonalized.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I think the rewrite catches the gist of the story as it was given by OP, but it lacks the crucial part who has the title to the car and who was issued the license plates that are on the car. (I assume Charly owns the title but he uses Bobs's plates)

Comment: Depending on how the sale was done, the government might not know about it, so the government will _believe_ that Bob is responsible. Just as if someone steals my car and parks it where they shouldn’t, government _believes_ that I’m responsible. So first Bob needs to convince the right government agency that it isn’t his car anymore.

Comment: @gnasher729: as a practical point, I agree with you. But in theory, if the storage company is seizing/selling the car to satisfy unpaid debts, I would imagine they would have to notify some government agency.